# Retrieve amino acids from fasta file and include its overall percentage for only the top 5 results

Tags: python, fasta

I want to display the amino acid, count and percentage for the top 5 but I can only manage the count and the amino acid with the script described below.  How could I update this?

L: 139002 (10.7%)
A: 123885 (9.6%)
G: 95475 (7.4%)
V: 91683 (7.1%)
I: 77836 (6.0%)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
def FASTA(filename):
  try:
    f = open(filename)
  except IOError:
    print ("The file, %s, does not exist" % filename)
    return

  order = []
  sequences = {}
  counts = {}

  for line in f:
    if line.startswith('>'):
      name = line[1:].rstrip('\n')
#      name = name.replace('_', ' ')
      order.append(name)
      sequences[name] = ''

    else:
      sequences[name] += line.rstrip('\n').rstrip('*')
      for aa in sequences[name]:
        if aa in counts:
            counts[aa] = counts[aa] + 1
        else:
            counts[aa] = 1


  print ("%d sequences found" % len(order))
  print (counts)
  return (order, sequences)

x, y = FASTA("/filepath")
```

Comment: Please provide a sample of your input.

Comment: There are repated sections of the following: There is always a line starting with >gi and then the amino acid sequences are below those (more than one line at times)


>gi|170079664|ref|YP_001728984.1| thr operon leader peptide [Escherichia coli str. K-12 substr. DH10B]
MKRISTTITTTITITTGNGAG